# Minimum number of samples for a cycles render of a simple image applied as a texture

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, hdri

I have a very simple animation of pages of a book being turned. I use Cycles and a hdri as the only light source. The pages are sitting on a black background with just a simple diffuse shader.
There is nothing complicated in the scene in regards to shading, each page has a principal bsdf, no reflection or specular. Just a 2048x2048 texture attached to base.

I wonder what would be the minimum of samples I could use for this scenario. Right now i am using 128 samples and I get around 15 seconds per frame. But I wonder if I could get away with less samples. Maybe 64, maybe 32 or maybe even less. Considering that there are no shadows, or reflections or anything except diffuse texture, it it possible to get away with maybe 2-3 samples?

I should of course do a simple test and check out, but I have 10 hours to wait for this render and I am curious if anyone encounter this scenario and maybe has a answer.

Comment: Hard to tell without having a file. You could upload your file here: https://blend-exchange.com/. If you want to figure out your minimum samples/settings correctly, I recommend to render a high quality image and a low quality image and check the differences between them (e.g. by subtracing the images in Blenders' shader graph or by using the Split Viewer of Blenders' Compositor).

Comment: There is a very simple answer to that question and you already know it: test it. How should we decide with what you can get away with? How should we know what is acceptable for you? The problem is, of course with a low sample rate you might need denoising. But how good or bad the result is and what is acceptable highly depends on your actual scene, the HDRI you are using and what you personally accept as result. And to check it out you don't need to render everything - render short bits of it. With 15 seconds at 128 samples it must be possible to render short animations with less samples.

Comment: Yes, i did test it. I could go as low as 64 samples. Unfortunately, the time difference isn't that great. I only lost about 2 seconds tops. I asked because i think i remembered reading somewhere that if there's only diffuse in the scene, theoretically it should work with even 1 sample. Anyway, in my scenario, 64 samples gives 99.9% result as 128 samples, but also about the same time. I hope this info could use to someone trying to render thousands of frames of flipping pages.